# IPv6 ACL in Packet Tracer - why doesn't it work?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, ipv6

I typed in this command:

```
 ipv6 access-list NO-SERVER-ACCESS
  permit ipv6 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 80
  permit ipv6 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 443
  permit ipv6 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 139
  permit ipv6 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 445
  exit
```

and got those error messages:

[image]

Could the reason be, that the emulated IOS in Packet Tracer doesn't know this command configured that way, because it's not up-to-date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include tcp/udp ports in your acl, you need to define the it a such in your rules, using "ipv6" would denote any ipv6 traffic. It should look more like this.

`ipv6 access-list NO-SERVER-ACCESS
  permit tcp 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 80
  permit tcp 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 443
  permit tcp 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 139
  permit tcp 2001:db8:18::/48 host 2001:db8:18:6600::0010 eq 445
  exit`

Comment: It works know... (the reason may be that I removed the first "deny ipv6 any any" - Statement, but it works know!